# issue counter and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, counter

I'm trying to find a way to make this letter counter operate, and it has to be using arrays in the letterCounter class. I'm confused on how to do this where it's concise. Here is the instruction I was given for this section:

If mychar is a lowercase letter, we can find the corresponding position in our count array with a
simple subtraction, like so:
counts[mychar - ’a’]
(That a is another magic value that you’ll eventually want to replace with a constant.)
So what about uppercase letters? Use the static method Character.toLowerCase(mychar).
Note: if (Character.toLowerCase(mychar) - ’a’) evaluates to something outside the range
[0, 25], then mychar is not a letter of the alphabet and should be ignored.
So, the process method you added earlier simply iterates over the characters in the String passed
in, and increments the value in the array, for each letter.
Similarly, the getCount method translates the character parameter into a position and returns the
count. Make sure you understand (and later document) what this method returns when the
argument is not a letter of the alphabet.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CounterDemo
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    LetterCounter cc = new LetterCounter();
    cc.process("foo");
    cc.process("supercalafrajalisticexpialadoscious");
    cc.process("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz");

    System.out.println("There are " + cc.getCount('z') + "z's");
}
}

public class LetterCounter {

public int getCount(char letter)
{
   // empty method for now

  return 0;
}

public void process(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

So would I just store 0-25 in an array and ask to return the letters if it's within that array?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your solution is a good solution, so the steps are: (pseudocode)

LetterCount class:
- has an array count[25]

Process func:

- scan each char
- if char -'a' is not a letter: continue
- count[char - 'a']++ (actually 'a' stands for 97, is the ascii value)

Getcount func

- return count[param.tolowercase - 'a']

Answer (score 0):

this is the basic solution... you still need to filter the results of getCount for alphabet chars only but that pretty much it

```
public class LetterCounter 
{
  public LetterCounter()
  {
      hash = new int[255];

      for (int i = 0; i < hash.length(); i++) hash[i] = 0;
  }

  private int[] hash;

  public int getCount(char letter)
  {
      return hash[(int)letter)];
  }

  public void process(String string) 
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++)
      {
         hash[(int)string.charAt(i)]++;
      }
  }

}
```